# GWTP Carstore sample application code splitting

Tags: gwt, gwtp, code-splitting

I launch the GWTP Carstore application

https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/carstore

in super development mode. It has numerous tabs, each corresponding to a place annotated with `@ProxyCodeSplit`, for example

```
@ProxyCodeSplit
@NameToken(NameTokens.MANUFACTURER)
interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<ManufacturerPresenter> {
}
```

Clicking on each tab, I expected that each time a different javascript file would be loaded; however this was not the case, as can be seen from the Fiddler screenshot I attach.

[image]

One sees that all the Javascript was loaded already during startup (the various requests returning JSON were sent to server as I clicked different tabs).

Is the Carstore application configuration incomplete, or perhaps I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if someone else comes to scratch his head over this: as I said, I saw that no code splitting occurred if I used Maven GWT plugin to launch Carstore in the super development mode, `mvn clean gwt:run`.

Trying to see whether no code splitting occurs also after deploying Carstore to Tomcat, I created the Carstore WAR with `mvn clean package`; it failed to deploy however (with Java 8, stack trace has

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:179)
```

inside).

So I experimented with a simpler project which I had on my machine. Likewise (at least with the Maven GWT plugin configuration in my project's pom.xml) I saw that in the super development mode all the Javascript gets loaded on startup. However when I created the WAR of this simpler project and deployed it (successfully this time) to Tomcat, I did see additional Javascript files being loaded after the "place" was changed. Thus, after deployment to Tomcat, code splitting worked as expected.